# Docker container Losing all file when start from cache

Tags: python, django, docker, pycharm, docker-for-windows

I am trying to create a Dockerfile for developing Django backend. However, when I finished my Dockerfile and tried to build it, a very strange error occurred. When my container was successfully built and automatically started, all the files I had copied into it were lost.

```
#dockerfile
FROM python:3.11.2

WORKDIR /Django

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENV WATCHPACK_POLLING=true

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
#CMD ["python"]
```

[Container build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thbf0.png)

```bash
Deploying 'Django Dockerfile: Dockerfile'…
Building image…
Preparing build context archive…
[==================================================>]140/140 files
Done

Sending build context to Docker daemon…
[==================================================>] 48.40kB
Done

Step 1/8 : FROM python:3.11.2
 ---> df3e9d105d6c
Step 2/8 : WORKDIR /Django
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e496b0316a98
Step 3/8 : COPY requirements.txt .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e6e1dd8df826
Step 4/8 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d64b72a3cd11
Step 5/8 : COPY . .
 ---> 0f61d894b1ea
Step 6/8 : ENV WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
 ---> Running in 5587dfc9c5fb
Removing intermediate container 5587dfc9c5fb
 ---> 5eb852bef2ae
Step 7/8 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Running in 3534176d6039
Removing intermediate container 3534176d6039
 ---> 9c9ab9c03246
Step 8/8 : CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
 ---> Running in fe97a0eab43e
Removing intermediate container fe97a0eab43e
 ---> 58ed83df5082

Successfully built 58ed83df5082
Existing container found: 485eabfc723df5463d9f3a7e4784e3f43ab118ba58c11c34213603e85948857e, removing…
Creating container…
Container Id: a0184f6cc50e06cbe189c44ae8962ab2cd893f4223c3227b789e6d4e65979446
Container name: 'Django'
Starting container 'Django'
```

[Container log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEQZ2.png)

I try to change the `CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]` to `CMD ["python"]` and used `ls` check the file, its empty.

[file check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EXhJ.png)

Then I found the last cache and used it to generate a container, and found that the process worked perfectly fine, which was the most peculiar part.

[Container from cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJZpn.png)

[working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be8AQ.png)

```bash
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
2023-04-20T10:43:50.818914463Z Performing system checks...
2023-04-20T10:43:50.818984773Z 
2023-04-20T10:43:50.905103187Z System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
2023-04-20T10:43:50.954496076Z 
2023-04-20T10:43:50.954545196Z You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
2023-04-20T10:43:50.954636019Z Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
2023-04-20T10:43:50.965569363Z April 20, 2023 - 10:43:50
2023-04-20T10:43:50.965617213Z Django version 4.2, using settings 'fit5120Django.settings'
2023-04-20T10:43:50.965624273Z Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
2023-04-20T10:43:50.965626713Z Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2023-04-20T10:43:50.965840952Z
```

#### Environment I'm using:

Windows 11
Docker for windows v4.17.1
PyCharm 2023.1 (Professional Edition)

#### Configuration setting

[Docker setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkmt4.png)

[configuration setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FBXZ.png)

In short, currently, the container built from my Dockerfile cannot run properly and will prompt an error stating that the file does not exist.

I don't know if this is a problem with my Dockerfile or a bug with Docker, but since I need to provide my team with a Docker to complete our task, I hope to solve this problem and enable my team to build containers correctly from the Dockerfile.

Comment: please attach the images within the question, instead of having it as hyperlinks

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  It's also a little unclear what the specific problem you're running into is – it sounds like some file might not be present in the built image? – and it would also help to clarify what file you're looking for, what results you get, and how you're actually running the container.

Comment: The container built from my Dockerfile cannot run properly and will prompt an error stating that the file does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was caused by permissions. The `-v` command requires permission, but I did not start PyCharm with administrator privileges, which caused the `-v` command to fail to map the files, resulting in all files being lost.